# ffmpeg, download video stream from url

Tags: ffmpeg

I am developing application to save any online webinar(video or audio) given the url using ffmpeg library. Url usually contain other contents like text, images as well. So i have problem, how to separately get video stream from url using ffmpeg(or some other better free library). Url may be for any site, not only for youtube, but as an example, link may be like

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnrJJYm7qIw

Answer (score 12):

the question is old but if anyone needs something like that, below is an example

```
ffmpeg -i "YOUR URL TO DOWNLOAD VIDEO FROM" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 "saveas.mp4"
```